# How to generate a unique ticket number using given sequence in PHP/Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to generate unique ticket number using the given sequence which is given format
C0000000001
C0000000002
C0000000003
C0000000004
C0000000005
C0000000006
C0000000007
C0000000008
C0000000009
C0000000010
C0000000011

Answer (score 0):

You can try using str_pad

**Code**

```
$max = 9;
for($x = 1; $x <= 11; $x++){

    echo 'C' .str_pad('', $max - strlen((string) $x), '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . $x . "<br />";
}
```

**Result**

```
C000000001
C000000002
C000000003
C000000004
C000000005
C000000006
C000000007
C000000008
C000000009
C000000010
C000000011
```